# How to avoid animation of text block in PowerPoint resetting when editing equations

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have noticed a persistent bug in PowerPoint (I don't know when I first observed it, but it is still present in the Office 365 suite, PowerPoint version 16.0.13801.20288, 64-bit).

If you have a text box containing equations and with a custom animation order and/or triggers, and you edit the equation, the the entire text box animation get reset to its default.

Steps to reproduce (one possible example)

- create a slide with the "title and content" layout
- type a few bullet points in the "content" text box, and insert a few equations
- create an ellipse
- selected the text box and the ellipse, then animations -> appear
- in the animation pane, expand the text box animation (so that you can see every bullet point). Make a few changes either in the trigger (appear on click/with previous/after previous) or even in the order of the various bullets (by dragging them around)
- drag the ellipse animation in between those of the bullets
- now select one of the equations in the text bo and edit it (add or remove a character)

Notice, by looking at the animation pane, that the text box animation has been reset, and the ellipse animation "expelled" from those of the text block.

Depending on the complexity of the text block and of the animation customization, this can be a very big inconvenience. Not to mention that its easy to spot and correct a mistake in an equation, not realizing that in doing so you have screwed up the entire animation... until it's too late!

Searching the web didn't turn out much, except for a couple of as of now locked threads in which the issue was reported, and the answer was basically to report it to customer support and wait for a fix:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_win10-mso_365hp/powerpoint-animation-pane-autoresets/3376891b-89fb-4a4b-b9ec-1d34d06d672d

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/animations-resetting-when-editing-an-equation/b4fec63c-6522-4157-92cf-85078522ff71

This at least confirmed that it is a known and reproducible bug.
Aside from waiting from a fix from Microsoft, how can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to the issue described. It won't save you if you correct an equation forgetting that you are screwing up the animation, but if you are aware and mindful of the issue, there is a very simple way of editing equations without the animation getting screwed up:

- create a new (temporary) text box
- type in this texbox a formula containing you correction: it can be a revised equation, a part of it or even a single character... for example if you just need to change a plus in a minus in the "original" (i.e. to be corrected) equation, you can just type a minus
- select this temporary expression, and copy it to the clipboard
- select the part of the "original" expression that you want to replace with the correction, and paste from the clipboard

You will notice that the animation has not been changed.

Tested on PowerPoint version 16.0.13801.20288, 64-bit and slightly earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this workaround works.  The key step seems to be editing the equation with content from the clipboard rather than directly from the keyboard. So enter the correct text in Notepad then copy and paste into the equation retains the animation. Even this works, and is simpler to implement on complex slides with lots of equations:

1. Duplicate the slide, with all of the animated equations
2. Edit and/or correct the equation(s) on the duplicate slide (this will clear all of the animations on the duplicate slide only)
3. Cut-and-paste the corrected equations ***individually*** from the duplicate slide over the relevant equations on the original slide (the animations in the original slide will remain unchanged!)
4. Delete the duplicate slide